# NSArray with days of the week and months of the year

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

Is there a way I can get an array of (string of days of the week) so: monday, tuesday, wednesday....
and also for months?

I can manually create that array, but I was wondering if there a more eloquent way of doing this...
Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, you think the names or number of days are going to change? With just 7 entries in one and 12 in the other array, I'm not sure what there is to gain over two static arrays.

Comment: @onnoweb, while you can do that, it doesn't provide localization. Bill Dudney's solution does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code;

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *weekdays = [dateFormatter weekdaySymbols];
```

will give you the the weekdays in the users current locale.

If you want a particular locale set the desired locale on the `dateFormatter`.

Creating an `NSDateFormatter` is expensive so create one and reuse it.